# How can I call a function in a vbscript with command line arguments?

Tags: vbscript, cmd, command-line-arguments

I have a script that executes remotely to see if a program is running. It works fine but I need it to check for several programs on several servers and I don't want to re-write it. I'm trying to see if I can call the function within the vbscript via command line so that I can use 1 script and change the arguments at the command line.

```
Function IsProcessRunning(strComputer, strProcess)
    Dim Process, strObject
    IsProcessRunning = 0
    strObject   = "winmgmts://" & strComputer
    For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
    If UCase( Process.name ) = UCase( strProcess ) Then
        IsProcessRunning = 1 
        If IsProcessRunning = 1 Then
            WScript.echo 1 & ": " & strProcess & " is currently running on " & strComputer      
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    Next
    WScript.echo 0 & ": " & strProcess " is NOT running on " & strComputer
End Function
```

What I'm hoping for is to be able to run this via cmd like:
 run.vbs IsprocessRunning Server3 Program2.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Why not to [use `WMIC`](https://www.google.ru/search?q=cmd%20wmic)? E. g. type in command line:

`wmic /node:server1 process where name='explorer.exe' get processid`

to get all launched explorers process ID on server1.

**SOURCE**

Use `WScript.Arguments` property:

```
IsProcessRunning WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1)

Function IsProcessRunning(strComputer, strProcess)
    Dim Process, strObject
    IsProcessRunning = 0
    strObject = "winmgmts://" & strComputer
    For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
        If UCase(Process.name) = UCase(strProcess) Then
            IsProcessRunning = 1 
            WScript.echo 1 & ": " & strProcess & " is currently running on " & strComputer      
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    WScript.echo 0 & ": " & strProcess & " is NOT running on " & strComputer
End Function
```

Better to add some check if the appropriate command line arguments provided to script.

Comment: thanks. the wscript.arguments works great. this is a script that will run on the back end of my network monitoring software so that is why it needs to be the vbscript and has to have the formatted echo.